# Python 3: Generic Windows service skeleton does not work, giving out error 1053

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have used the "generic skeleton" for making a test service. After installing it, I have tried to launch it from service manager and:

1. A popup window appears. It contains a progress bar.
2. Then when on approx. half, it stops, closes and gives out error 1053

Here's the "generic skeleton":

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "LULUKWORKER"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Luluk Service"


    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(1000)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                          (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        # Your business logic or call to any class should be here
        # this time it creates a text.txt and writes Test Service in a daily manner 
        f = open('C:\\Users\\User\\test.txt', 'w')
        rc = None
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            f.write('Test Service  \n')
            f.flush()
            # block for 20 seconds and wait for a stop event
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 20 * 1000)
        f.write('shut down \n')
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```